# Web user control's private value is empty after UpdatePanel updates

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, webusercontrol

1. I have a web user control which has an update panel & a gridview is inside it
2. On page load I set user control's private field value through a publicly exposed property & bind the gridview with data
3. I enter some new values in through a modal & do a postback inside the updatepanel in user control, when I try to fetch the value of private field on my user control  the value is default to zero

> ```
>  private int ftId = 0;
>
> public int  FtId
> {
>     set { ftId = value; }
> }
> ```

the private `int ftId=0;` is called after every ASync postback.
Is there any way I can overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a value in a variable and have it persist across postbacks.  But storing it in viewstate will work:

```
public int  FtId
{
    get { return  (int)(ViewState["FtId"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["FtId"] = value; }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: It says ?? can't be applied to 'int' 'int' though I do agree with your viewstate logic.

Comment: Also, if I access FtId inside user control it says it does not exist in current context.

Comment: ?? is for nullable types, so yes it can't be applied directly to int, but ViewState["FtId"] is an object.. I do this as the viewstate may not have been loaded for a user... it should let you do it, I have this syntax in other places...  Also, how are you accessing it?  It should work just like a property.  Do you mean "inside same user control" or from another user control?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I got it to work by using get { return (int?)ViewState["ftId"] ?? 0; } I can access the property now from all methods. Thank you man.